# Why is the net force maximal at maximal displacement in a suspended spring?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, spring

When at maximum displacement, the $x$ and $U$ are max., $K$ and $v$ are $0$. But why is net force max.?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the questions shows no evidence of effort.

Comment: Do not use too many abbreviations.

Comment: Are you talking about harmonic oscillator or just a body at rest when suspended from the spring?

Comment: Harmonic oscillator

Answer (score 2):

$$F = -kx$$

By definition, the amplitude $A$ is the maximum displacement from the mean position.

$$F_{max} = -kA$$

The spring force increases as the stretching increases.

Answer (score 0):

There is a constant force downwards on the mass due to the weight of the mass.
Because the spring is stretched to its maximum extent at the bottom of the motion the upward force on the mass is a maximum at this position.
At the top of the motion the spring is stretched to its minimum extent and producing a minimum upward force, so at this position the downward force on the mass is a maximum.

Comment: Sorry i forgot to mention that it is the net force that I am talking about .Won't the net force be 0 as they cancel each other ? My understanding of the suspended spring's mechanism is not that much so I didn't want to write why I didn't think so

Comment: They don't cancel each other. They cancel each other at the mean position. At the maximum displacement position, the spring force is larger than weight. This is why the weight goes back to the mean position.